# How to find out why a function passed the test in Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

Is there a way to show why tested function can pass?

When I follow Jest [test Async Code section](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#promises)

It says:

> Be sure to return the promise - if you omit this return statement,
>   your test will complete before fetchData completes.

And my code is:

```
function add1(n) {
  return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
    res(n+1)
  })
}


test('should add 1', function() {
    expect.assertions(1)
    //////////////////////////// I did not use RETURN here
    add1(10).then((n11)=>{
        expect(n11).toBe(11)
    })
});
```

This still passed, I want to know how this can pass?

Comment: Why? Usually because it produced the expected result. Can you explain further what you mean?

Comment: @mypetlion question updated

Comment: What you've posted won't pass, as it refers to names that don't exist (what is `add1`?) But the reason a test would incorrectly pass if you didn't return the promise is **explained by the blockquote you've included** - because the test completes before the failing expectation is reached. You don't return the promise to make the test pass, you return the promise *to make the test able to fail*.

Comment: @mypetlion  Sorry, I that function name should be add1, my bad. But the test does pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Promise` resolves immediately and synchronously so the `then` gets called immediately and the `expect` has run before the test finishes.  (`then` callbacks run immediately if the `Promise` has already resolved)

If you use `setTimeout` to keep the `Promise` from resolving immediately and synchronously then the test fails unless you return the `Promise`:

```js
function add1(n) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => { res(n + 1) }, 0);  // use setTimeout
  })
}

test('should add 1', function () {
  expect.assertions(1)
  // PASSES only if Promise is returned
  return add1(10).then((n11) => {
    expect(n11).toBe(11);
  })
});
```

Comment: (I'm assuming `fetchData` should have been `add1` and that the extra fat arrow was a typo)

Comment: Yes, the function name should be add1. Thanks, get it. I guess it is just my understanding about Promise is wrong.